# FileProvider NPE null object reference

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

Hi I'm currently experiencing error on starting an intent due to FileProvider causing NPE. I followed the steps provided [here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en) but I still got the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I am not sure as well if the provider_paths.xml is being used here. Here's my code so far:

Manifest:

```
<application>... <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider></application>
```

res/xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

code:

```
Uri uri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider", file);
```

the itself seems to be the cause of error here.

Comment: I'm not sure why I get a down vote on this question. I know some will say this is a duplicate but I already checked on every solution I can find here and it all says the same. For now I opt to just use:

StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

sad thing SO community. :(

Answer (score 0):

BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID should return your packagename, however, in my case it returned "android.support.v4". I consider using getPackagename() and it will work just fine!

So just change

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
```

to:

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                            getPackagename() + ".provider", file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link for your answer.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46550472/fileprovider-geturiforfile-returns-nullpointerexception)

First, this:

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
```

you are using this:

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
```

chabge this :

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", file);
```

Since I don't know which of those is what you really want, I cannot suggest a fix.

Answer (score -1):

I am using this :

**Manifest :**

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

**XML file :**

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="media_folder" path="." />
</paths>
```

**In Java :**

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
```

Comment: Sadly, it is just the same thing I used.

Comment: Glad to hear that but it is not for me. I'm using device working with Android N

Comment: It is useful in android n only. Please try using this <external-path name="media_folder" path="." />